# jQuery ajax Data Sent to Controller are Empty only in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my jQuery code :

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "/Ajax/GetConcertTime",
     type: "POST",
     cache: false,
     data: { concertID: concertID.replace("ct", ""), date: selectedDateValue },
     success: function (dataFromServer) {
                 //some codes ...
              },
      error: function (a, b, c) {
                    alert(c);
              }
  });
```

And this is my controller code for catching parameters :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetConcertTime(string concertId, string date)
{
     int cid = Convert.ToInt32(concertId);
     try
     {
           MelliConcertEntities db = new MelliConcertEntities();
           var lst = (from x in db.Showtimes
                           where x.Concert.ID == cid
                           && x.ShowtimeDate.Equals(date)
                           && x.IsActive == true
                           select x.ShowtimeTime).Distinct().ToList();
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return Content(js.Serialize(lst));
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
           return Content(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

After debugging i know the parameters in Controller (concertId and date) are empty when i using IE browser.but in other browser it's work properly.
What should i do for this issue?

Comment: Where are said values coming from? have you confirmed that the variables you are using to send the data actually contain data when they are used?

Comment: Yes,data sent to server,i checked values with alert them before ajax code,i said in other browser it's working only ie has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try a straight forward jquery POST :

```
     $.post("/Ajax/GetConcertTime", { "concertID" : concertID.replace("ct", ""),
              "date":  selectedDateValue }, function (response) {
            console.log(response);  //do your thing

      }).error(function()
            {
                //your stuff
            });
```

Comment: Can you check if the above code is working, what response are you getting in your response?

Comment: it has the same problem , the values in controller are empty.

Comment: Before sending to the controller can you check if you are getng values for :
console.log(concertID.replace("ct", ""));
console.log(selectedDateValue);

Comment: Yes,the values are OK.

Comment: Are you getting any response? If yes , can you post it here please.